# Envira Gallery - Uncaught ReferenceError:

Tags: javascript, gallery, referenceerror

I'm a newbie here looking for some direction. I have searched for an answer to this topic on this forum and have come to a dead-end. I need to know how to fix Javascript error I found on my Console that is causing my gallery images not to appear on my gallery page. They're there but not visible.

Here is the copied error message from my console.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
at envira-min.js?ver=1.6.1.4:9
at envira-min.js?ver=1.6.1.4:9

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).enviratope is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):325)
at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
```

After reading a bit of the support pages on Envira, I think I might have two copies of JS installed. I have gone through the files and Im not sure what I am looking for, so that I can fix it. So, I am hoping someone can assist me with direction. Please.

The page in question is:
http://devsite.laaperformingarts.org/media/

Answer (score 0):

The `module is not defined` error is caused by one of your plugins creating a global `exports` variable. The envira plugin sees this and mistakenly thinks it can use requirejs to load the jquery library. A simple fix for this would be to change the order of your script tags so that envira loads before the file that is creating this global variable.

Make sure the order of your script tags in the HTML has

`<script type='text/javascript' src='http://devsite.laaperformingarts.org/wp-content/plugins/envira-gallery-lite/assets/js/min/envira-min.js?ver=1.6.1.4'></script>`

before

`<script type='text/javascript' src='http://devsite.laaperformingarts.org/wp-content/themes/royal/layout/plugins/retina/retina.min.js?ver=4.8'></script>`

Comment: Thank you, Brett,

That seems like a very simple solution... but I can't seem to find that script anywhere on my files. I have checked the index.php and header.php files for that script. I am using Wordpress 4.8 if that helps.  I have also gone through other files using Cyberduck. Would you be able to direct me on where I can make those changes?

Thanks for your patience with me.